# How find Components in a Frame

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I'm a Java newbie learning Swing... Hopefully this is really simple.

I've created a `JFrame` and added a `MenuBar` and a `Panel` . . . When I press run, the window pops up showing the menu and the panel... So it works till here... now lets do something with it..

I have set the `visibility` of the `Panel` and `MenuBar` reference variables in MainFrame.java file as `private`..

The problem is, I want to access those variables... E.g: - I want to add content to the `Panel` and/or enable/disable things in the `Menu(s)`.

But all that I am holding is a handle to the main `JFrame`.

How can I get a handle to the Menu or to the Panel?

I could add accessor methods to the `MainFrame.java` file . . . but I think Java might have some standard way of doing this. . . and if accessor methods were the typical way of handling this, I would assume they'd be provided by the NetBeans GUI Builder.

What am I missing?

Frank

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://example.com), probably nobody knows if you need constructor, MVC, components tree or ... ???

Comment: What is a SSCCE . . . (the link doesn't go anyplace useful)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accessor methods is a good way to go.

Another way would be to do something like an inversion of control. Instead of getting references to your menu and panel objects from another classes, you could call methods in the main frame class to do the work on the menu and panel that you need to be done in the other classes.

Another choice would be to navigate through the component graph, but I would not recommend that because whenever you will add / remove components to your panels in the frame, you will have to change the logic that retrieves the references to the menu and panel that you need.

Comment: Thanks for reminder about inversion of control . . . I like that even better.